# Cant Bind UIButton and UITextField in ViewModel with Xamarin-iOS and ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, reactive-programming, reactiveui

I have LoginViewController class

```
// This file has been autogenerated from a class added in the UI designer.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive;
using ReactiveUI;
using GoBatumi.IOS.ViewModels;

namespace GoBatumi.IOS
{
    public partial class LogInViewController : ReactiveViewController,IViewFor<LoginViewModel>
    {      
        UITapGestureRecognizer SingUpGesture;
        public LogInViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
            this.WhenActivated(d =>
            {
                d(this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.UserName, vm => vm.userNameTextField.Text));
                d(this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Password, vm => vm.passwordTextField.Text));
                d(this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.LoginButton, vm => vm.logInButton));
                d(this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.PasswordTextField, vm => vm.passwordTextField));
            });
        }

        private void MakeViewModelBinding(){
        }

        public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews(){
            base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();   
        }

        LoginViewModel _viewModel;
        public LoginViewModel ViewModel 
        {
            get => _viewModel ?? new LoginViewModel();
            set => _viewModel = value;
        }
        object IViewFor.ViewModel 
        {
            get => ViewModel;
            set => ViewModel = (LoginViewModel)value; 
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad(){
            base.ViewDidLoad();
        }

        private void ShouldChangeViewSettings(bool enable){
            passwordTextField.Enabled = enable;
            logInButton.Enabled = enable;         
            if (enable)
                logInButton.Alpha = 0.99f;
            else
                logInButton.Alpha = 0.4f;
        }
    }

    public class TestUser
    {
        public string UserName{
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Password{
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I have LoginViewModel class

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using ReactiveUI;
using UIKit;

namespace GoBatumi.IOS.ViewModels
{
    public class LoginViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        public LoginViewModel()
        {
        }

        private string _userName;
        public string UserName
        {
            get => _userName;
            set
            {
                this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _userName, value);
                var result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_userName);

                ShouldChangeViewSettings(result);
            }
        }


        private string _password;
        public string Password
        {
            get => _password;
            set
            {
                this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _password, value);
            }    

        }

        private UIButton _loginButton;
        public UIButton LoginButton
        {
            get => _loginButton;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _loginButton, value);
        }

        private UITextField _passwordTextField;
        public UITextField PasswordTextField
        {
            get => _passwordTextField;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _passwordTextField, 
        }

    }
}
```

My problem is that string username and string password can bind with,
usernameTextField.Texts and passwordTextField.Text

But it UIButton and UITextField are always null, they haven't bound.

My task is that whenever the user types a character into textField I must enable the button, and whenever a user deletes the wholeTextfield and if the string is empty, I must disable button again, so I need UiButton for changing the background color from ViewModel but UIButtonProperty always returns null.

Where is the problem?

I will be very glad if someone will give me a piece of advice.
I'm a little bit new into MVVM and into ReactiveUi.

Thanks.

Comment: You dont need a UITextField  and UIButton  on your ViewModel.You need a ReactiveCommand, ReactiveCommand defines a IObservable<bool> called CanExecute and by combinig it with a WhenAnyValue operator you can achieve your goal

Comment: But how can I communicate from viewmodel to ViewController's objects like those button and uitextfield ? Can you write a little example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few suggestions:

- Your view models should never reference anything platform/view related (get rid of the UITextField and UIButton members). View models are meant to be platform independent, so they can be reused and testable.
- Use [ReactiveCommands](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/an-example). They handle enabling/disabling the button automagically. If you check this documentation link, you'll find essentially the exact same example code/scenario.
- Use the [generic version](https://github.com/Qonstrukt/ReactiveUI/blob/63f99c0f7831261ff307726019782f7009d4f62a/src/ReactiveUI/Cocoa/ReactiveNSViewController.cs) of ReactiveViewController so you don't have to worry about implementing the ViewModel properties yourself (your version should have used RaiseAndSetIfChanged, as you'll see in the link).

...

```
public class LoginViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public LoginViewModel()
    {
        var canLogin = this.WhenAnyValue(
            x => x.UserName,
            x => x.Password,
            (userName, password) => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password));
        LoginCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(
            LoginAsync, // A method that returns IObservable<Unit>
            canLogin);
    }

    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> LoginCommand { get; }

    private string _userName;
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return _userName; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _userName, value); }
    }

    private string _password;
    public string Password
    {
        get { return _password; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _password, value); }
    }
}
```

...

```
public partial class LogInViewController : ReactiveViewController<LoginViewModel>
{      
    UITapGestureRecognizer SingUpGesture;

    public LogInViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        this.WhenActivated(d =>
        {
            d(this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.UserName, v => v.userNameTextField.Text));
            d(this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Password, v => v.passwordTextField.Text));
            d(this.BindCommand(ViewModel, vm => vm.LoginCommand, v => v.logInButton));
        });
    }
}
```

Here's a [heavily documented ViewModel](https://github.com/paulcbetts/XamarinEvolve2014/blob/46bac6c09f6683cfbefd4a975ff10377d8ad68a7/XamarinEvolve-Core/ViewModels/LoginStartViewModel.cs), along with the corresponding sample project to help you get headed in the right direction. And I highly recommend the book, "[You, I, and ReactiveUI](https://kent-boogaart.com/you-i-and-reactiveui/)" if you really want to become proficient. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry my newbie questions, but how can I make LoginCommand Observable, which can disable or enable button?

Comment: The LoginCommand is an observable, so it will enable/disable the button automatically in the above code. It knows when to enable/disable the button based on the _canLogin_ variable. The condition I used was `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName)` and `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password)`

Comment: When I'm trying to bind my button to the Command this exception occurs. [  Can't two-way convert between ReactiveUI.ReactiveCommand`2[System.Reactive.Unit,System.Reactive.Unit] and UIKit.UIButton. To fix this, register a IBindingTypeConverter or call the version with converter Funcs.]

Comment: In your example, LoginCommand is readonly so I cannot bind it from my view.

Comment: If I will make write setter for it like loginComand = value, this cause exception

Comment: How do you bind command? You should use `this.BindCommand` not use `this.Bind` like in here https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/binding-commands

Answer (score 1):

Ok friend if I understand correctly, you can have do something like this:

In your ViewModel:

```
public ReactiveCommand<Unit,Unit> LoginCommand { get; set; }

    public LoginViewModel()
    {
        //this operator does the magic, when UserName and Password be different than empty your button
        //will be enabled
        var canLogin = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.UserName, x=> x.Password, 
                                        (user,password) => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password));

        LoginCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<Unit, Unit>(async _ =>
        {
            //Your login logic goes here..
            return Unit.Default;
        }, canLogin);

    }
```

And in your View

```
 public LogInViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        this.WhenActivated(d =>
        {
            d(this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.UserName, vm => vm.userNameTextField.Text));
            d(this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Password, vm => vm.passwordTextField.Text));
            d(this.BindCommand(this.ViewModel,vm => vm.LoginCommand,v => v.LoginButton));
        });
    }
```

your view and your viewmodel interacts via command binding.

I hope this helps you.